# Скорость сравнения двух массивов char

Tags: c++, c

Вдруг возник такой простой вопрос: нужно просто сравнить два массива чаров.

Собстно это можно сделать минимум тремя способами:
-простым сравнением и перебором
-через strncmp (сравниваем массивы с указанием длинны)
-через strcmp(сравнивает массивы с \0)

И у меня вопрос по скорости выполнения эти трех методов, я че то кое чего не понимаю, вот простейший код для тестирования:

```
char my_char1[] = {1,5,45,255,56,45,1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45,'\0'};
 
 
char my_char2[] = { 1,5,45,255,56,45,1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45, 1,5,45,255,56,45,'\0'};
```

Сравниваю сначала равные, потом не равные массивы:

1)Через перебор:

```
#include <ctime>
 
 
int stat = 0;
 
int clock1 = clock();
 
for (int y = 0; y < 100000000; y++)
{
 
    stat = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(my_char2); i++)
    {
        if (my_char1[i] != my_char2[i])
        {
            stat = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
 
int clock2 = clock();
 
cout << stat << endl;
cout << clock2-clock1<< endl;
```

2)Через strncmp:

```
int stat = 0;
 
 
int clock1 = clock();
for (int y = 0; y < 100000000; y++)
{
    stat = 0;
    if (strncmp(my_char1, my_char2, sizeof(my_char2)) != 0)
    {
        stat = 1;
    }
 
}
int clock2 = clock();
 
cout << stat << endl;
cout << clock2-clock1<< endl;
```

3)Через strcmp:

```
int stat = 0;
 
 
int clock1 = clock();
for (int y = 0; y < 100000000; y++)
{
    stat = 0;
    if (strcmp(my_char1, my_char2) != 0)
    {
        stat = 1;
    }
}
int clock2 = clock();
 
cout << stat << endl;
cout << clock2-clock1<< endl;
```

И вот результаты по скорости (в release) по сравнению равных массивов:

1)3500 (мс)
2)1580 (мс)
3)0 (мс)

У меня собственно два вопроса:
-Почему между перебором и strncmp - такая разница в целых два раза ?
-И почему у strcmp - такая скорость ???

А вот результаты по скорости по сравнению не равных массивов, не равны они сразу в 1 элементе:
1)60 (мс)
2)232 (мс)
3)0 (мс)

Ну strcmp остается, а вот перебор в этом случае теперь 4 раза быстрее strncmp.

Почему так или что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Скорее всего сработала оптимизация, и оба массива имеют один указатель, если они одинаковые.

Comment: Нужно смотреть, чего там компилятор сгенерировал. Навскидку предположу: второй вариант быстрее первого, потому что сравнение идёт не по одному байту, а сразу по несколько. Третий вариант быстрее всех потому, что компилятор понял, что нет нужды 100000000 раз крутить цикл, ибо на итоговый результат это не повлияет.

Comment: сдесь еще важно понимать как вы проводили тесты: как замеряли время и с какой оптимизацией вы компилировали (или без нее)

Comment: VC++ просто оптимизирует, выбрасывая цикл вообще...

Comment: Andrej Levkovitch, время замерял, как показано в коде. Запускал код в VS2027 - там указан оптимизация по скорости.

Comment: wololo, если бы разница между 1ым и 2ым способом была только в "потому что сравнение идёт не по одному байту, а сразу по несколько", то тогда, когда идет сравнение не равного массива с самого первого элемента - то скорости были бы равны, а тут у перебора скорость выше оказалась.

Comment: Не всё так просто. `strncmp` наверняка начинает свою работу с некоторых подготовительных действий. Например, вычисляет сколько n-байтных блоков содержат входные массивы или проверяет правильно ли выровнены переданные ей указатели и, если нет, то вначале производит побайтовое сравнение. У первого варианта никаких подготовительных действий нет, поэтому на массивах, различающихся в первом элементе, первый вариант оказывается быстрее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если заставить **не выбрасывать** цикл, например, так:

```cpp
int stat = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < 100000000; y++)
{
    if (strcmp(my_char1, my_char2) == 0)
    {
        stat += 1;
    }
}
```

то VC++2019 с полной оптимизацией дает (у меня) такие результаты:

- сравнение вручную - 4070 мс
- strncmp - 2080 мс
- strcmp - 55 мс

Если переписать сравнение вручную через int -

```cpp
for (const int *a = (const int *)my_char1, *b = (const int *)my_char2;
     (char*)a < my_char1 + sizeof(my_char1); a++, b++)
{
    if (*a != *b)
```

время уменьшается примерно до 1600 мс.

Думаю, в вызове `str[n]cmp` активно применяются разнообразнейшие возможности оптимизации :)

Да, для x64 -

- сравнение вручную - 4090 мс / 1140 мс (через int)
- strncmp - 920 мс
- strcmp - 58 мс

Многократно с усреднением не считал, так что цифры примерные.

Comment: А он точно не выбрасывает? Не делает ли он так: `if (strcmp(my_char1, my_char2) == 0) stat += 100000000`? И если не делает, то как заставить делать? :)

Comment: Надо же, как размер, наряду со сравнением на конец строки, влияет! / Кстати, а какие строки сравнивали?

Comment: @wololo VC++2019 не делает. Смотрел ассемблерный листинг.

Comment: @avp Да те же, что у автора вопроса. Полный код [тут](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/7ad994a21d3738c2197545ce1099af3f2135c653/quest/1203775.cpp).